# What do I need to declare about data collection and analytics tools if I only use admob?

Tags: admob, privacy, privacy-policy

I have an app that is a basic game with admob implementation. I collect no data myself.

Most policy generators ask questions like:
 - "What kind of personal information you collect from users?" 
 - "Do you use tracking and/or analytics tools"

What kind of personal info does AdMob collect? 
Does AdMob use any tracking or analytics stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re asking the right questions. You are the data controller, and admob is one of your data processors, so it’s your responsibility to ensure that admob treats your users data appropriately. So that means you need to answer those questions, which hopefully will be covered in admob’s own privacy policy and terms & conditions, so I recommend you go find them!

You can’t safely gloss over this because if admob does anything wrong (e.g. they have a data breach), it’s you that will be held responsible, as far as your users are concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about looking at AdMob's Privacy policy! It led me to [this helpful terms and conditions tutorial](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-admob/) for apps that use it!